# Изменение цвета и выравнивание текста по центру

Tags: java, android

Для вставки текста на Activity использую элемент TextView и хочу сделать это, используя html, следующим образом:

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text1.setText(Html.fromHtml("Какой-то текст");
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как данный текст выровнять по ширине и изменить его цвет. Пробовал так, но результата не было:

```
fromHtml("<p align=\"center\">Какой-то текст" </p>");
```

Какие есть варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Здесь (http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.by/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html)  перечислены поддерживаемые классом `Html` тэги. `align`  среди них нет.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш элемент TextView описан в layout вашей Activity. Для выравнивания по ширине установите ему атрибут android:gravity="start|end" . Цвет, которым он должен отображаться устанавливается атрибутом android:textColor

Comment: По ширине - android:gravity="center_horizontal". "start" - к левому краю, "end" - к правому краю

Comment: @user212681 Чтобы выравнивание по ширине сработало, android:layout_width должно быть шире ширины текста, например, "match_parent"